# how to change add to cart button into view in cart button in angular + ngrx shopping app ..?

Tags: html, angular

I am building a shopping app using angular + ngrx . in product list component i want my "add to cart" button changes to "view in cart" if item is present in cart.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="action">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Action</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let product; let cart">
        <div *ngIf="product.productId !== cart.productId">
          <button
            (click)="addToCart(product)"
            mat-raised-button
            color="primary"
          >
            <mat-icon>
              add_shopping_cart
            </mat-icon>
            Add to Cart
          </button>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="product.productId === cart.productId">
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary">
            <mat-icon>
              shopping_cart
            </mat-icon>
            View in Cart
          </button>
        </div>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: what is the behavioral change does the above code made?

Comment: have you tried debugging `product.productId and  cart.productId` values?